# Find out background color of highlighted text in MS Word document using C# or VBA

Tags: c#, vba, office-interop, ms-word

Following finds the highlighted text in a Word document (even if the different text at different places is highlighted with different colors). How can we find out the background color of each highlighted text. I'm using C# but VBA will also be ok:

```
With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
  .Highlight = True
  While .Execute
    Debug.Print .Parent.Text
  Wend
End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below statement would get you the color index of selected text in MS Word

```
Dim objSelection As Selection
Set objSelection = Application.Selection
Msgbox objSelection.FormattedText.HighlightColorIndex
```

The value returned is one of wdColorIndex enumeration. List of values in enumeration can be seen here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb237561(v=office.12).aspx

**Update#1**

Below code is using ActiveDocument.Range.Find as requested

```
Dim objSelection As Selection
Dim temp As String

With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
  .Highlight = True
  While .Execute
    'Store the text for searching later
    temp = .Parent.Text

    'Select all the text
    ActiveDocument.Content.Select

    'Find and select the text
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = temp
    End With

    If Selection.Find.Execute Then
        Selection.Select
    End If

    'Now that we've selected it, get the HighlightedColorIndex
    Set objSelection = .Application.Selection
    MsgBox .Parent.Text & vbNewLine & "Index: " & objSelection.FormattedText.HighlightColorIndex
  Wend
End With
```

Comment: I need to find the color of highlighted text (not to set it). `objSelection.ParagraphFormat.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor` returns  9999999 for all highlighted text regardless of what color the text is highlighted with.

Comment: the `Find` object does not have `FormattedText` property. How do you find the background color of a highlighted text that you find using the `Find` object (shown in the code of my original post).

Comment: Please see my Update#1